# How can I replace my windows partition with another Ubuntu based distro, in a dual boot system?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

If I wanted to replace my windows partition (in a dual boot system, Windows XP/Lubuntu) with another Ubuntu-based distro, how would I do it? Would I just overwrite the Windows partition using the third option of the Ubuntu installer? If so, do I have to do something else (like creating additional partitions), or just point the installer in the direction of the partition to be replaced (overwrite)? My partition table is this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x43c4e8b6

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63   160682129    80341033+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       292045635   312560639    10257502+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       160684030   292044799    65680385    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       160684032   289968127    64642048   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       289970176   292044799     1037312   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdc: 8000 MB, 8000110592 bytes
160 heads, 19 sectors/track, 5139 cylinders, total 15625216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1              32    15625215     7812592    b  W95 FAT32
johnny@johnny-FQ652AA-ABA-CQ2009F-NA910:~$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should first delete the unwanted partition(s) and point the installer to the empty space created.

Comment: Ok, got it (using the installer partition tool), but nothing else needs to be done?

Comment: If you want you can use some of that space to first create a swap partition. If not that is basically it. Try and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't care what was on the Windows partition (files, programs, etc) you could overwrite it by pointing the installer at that partition. If you still want the files on Windows, you would need to back those files up (or the enitire OS if you wanted) to external storage.

Comment: No, I actually have nothing of relevance there. The only thing holding me of doing it, is the doubt of whether something else needs to be done, besides pointing the partition to the installer as a sure target of obliteration.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you dont need to make a separate installation if your existing ubuntu installation is updated one (why do the unnecessary extra work?). It will be easy if your windows partitions are immediately near (continous) linux root partition.

1. Boot to windows, make any windows primary paritions as logical, using maybe EaseUs partition manager. https://superuser.com/questions/552441/how-to-convert-a-primary-partition-to-logical
2. Boot from a live media containing Gparted.
3. Delete any windows partitions, and then expand your existing linux `root` (/) partition.

If your existing ubuntu is too old, then you will be completely running ubuntu on your box, and in that case, you dont have to worry about *anything* at all. Just delete the whole paritions, including the other ubuntu one. Be sure to have a `swap` partition.

I appreciate your willingness to completely wipe away wondoz. Its a **milestone**! :)

Comment: At first I thought about expanding my Lubuntu partition, but later I decided to try out Bhodi Linux, so I can dual boot with it. I think I will go with this option :-)

Comment: If you have some serious plans to do distro hopping, and you are not faint hearted, this might help http://aurabindo.in/tutorials/2014/03/23/happy-distro-hopping/ :P

Comment: You are welcome, and if you dont mind, I'm badly in need of 29 reputations! :)

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it was AuqustinJ suggested: Delete and then install. The procedure was as follows:

- Selecting the third option in the installer (as this was a
  Ubuntu-based distro, the installer was the same) I selected the
  windows partition for edit, then format as Ext4
- Then, I selected the mounting point (in this case, /)
- After that, just hit install. Presto!

Everything went down smoothly. The only side-effect was the clutter in my Grub, after reboot...

[image]